# Control flow and Processing of XSLT file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I know XSLT is a declarative language and does not describe control flow . But how does the processors determines or converts the XML file using XSLT file ? Do they use different computation process for conversion ? How does loops such as foreach loop or sorting or if statements work without control flow ?

Comment: Well, this is an excellent question, but not one for this forum. You need to do some reading: about XSLT, about compiler writing in general and compilers for functional languages in particular. Get some good computer science books, or if you prefer, study the code of an open-source XSLT processor such as Saxon.

Answer (score 1):

**The best way to get answers to these three questions is to do some serious reading**.

This list of resources will probably help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/341589/36305

Answer (score -1):

This is like asking "How does programming work?". The question is so broad, a fair answer could not be encapsulated in a few paragraphs.

- If you want a quick, but supremely thin overview, then look up XSLT in wikipedia.
- If you want a quick, but a little thicker overview, try w3c schools tutorial website.
- If you are serious, buy a book. Just search in your favourite book store. I recommend this one: "XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference (Programmer to Programmer)" [http://www.amazon.com/XSLT-XPath-Programmers-Reference-Programmer/dp/0470192747/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1337849053&sr=8-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470192747)

Some luminary could give you a couple of paragraphs of explanation on XSLT works, but this explanation would be pretty much the same as what you can find by yourself on wikipedia.

Comment: None of your references is likely to explain the internal workings of an XSLT processor.

Comment: I am not sure he is asking about the internal workings of an XSLT processor from the perspective of compiler design. Perhaps he is, but the way I read it, he is asking for an overview of the language. I take his last question "How does loops such as foreach loop or sorting or if statements work without control flow ?" as a point of evidence. Obviously English is not his mother tongue. The question is sufficiently imprecise and poorly worded, that I don't think it is fair to down-vote my answer because I have a different interpretation of the question.

Comment: Sean is suggesting the same book that is in Dimitre reading list - his answer seems as valid to me.